# fdopen: Invalid arguement

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to create and open a file with `fopen` and `fdopen` to write some content.
Below is the code I wrote:

```
    char Path[100];
    int write_fd;

    snprintf(Path,100,"%s/%s","/home/user","myfile.txt");
    printf("opening file..\n");
    write_fd = open(Path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777);

    if(write_fd!=-1)
    { 
       printf(" write_fd!=-1\n");

       FILE *file_fp = fdopen(write_fd,"a+");

       if (file_fp == NULL)
       {
              printf("Could not open file.File pointer error %s\n", std::strerror(errno));
              close(write_fd);
               return 0;         
       }
       write(write_fd, "First\n", 7);
       write(write_fd, "Second\n", 8);
       write(write_fd, "Third\n", 7);
       fclose(file_fp);
   }
```

The file fd `write_fd` is created with the permissions WRONGLY which should have permission to read/write(?). But when `fdopen` called on the file descriptor with mode `a+`, it is throwing error saying Invalid Argument.

It is successfully opened with mode `a`.

What exactly differs between the modes `a` and `a+` that causes this error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `a+` mode means *append* and *read*.

Since you have initially opened the file in write-only mode (`O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL`), read access is not compatible with the mode of the initial descriptor.

Therefore, the call to [fdopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) rightfully fails with `EINVAL`.